# laravel many to many relationship between 3 tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables `category`,`product` and `store`.One product can be in multiple categories and Store can have multiple categories and product.

I know how to setup `many-to-many` relationship between 2 tables in laravel using pivot tables.However,regarding 3 tables,its getting a bit complicated.What is the best approach to setup `many-to-many` relationship between 3 tables using laravel framework ?

Comment: The answer to your question is actually available in the Laravel official documentation, you could use Many-to-many Polymorphic relationships within Laravel in this kind of situation. Assuming you're using Laravel 5.2, details are in this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations